# Manifest for DLL - To check Windows 10 compatibility (Use version helper APIs)

Tags: windows, dll, manifest, compatibility

Environment:

Visual Studio 2015/Visual C++

OS: Windows 10 TH2 10586 / Corresponding Windows SDK

---

Since GetVersionEx is deprecated in Windows 8 and later, I wanted to use version helper APIs (IsWindows10OrGreater) to detect the OS in my DLL to decide the flow. However, as per the MSDN documentation, I will need to have a manifest (with compatibility section for supported OS versions) without which this API (IsWindows10OrGreater) will return false even if running in Windows 10.

I have added a manifest with the required compatibility sections but I could not still get it to work. It always returns false. (I have defined manifest ID as 2 in my resource.h as it is DLL)

To cross check, I implemented a sample standalone application with same manifest which works perfectly for this version helper API.

I need your help to understand what am I missing here in the DLL? Unfortunately, none of the discussions available online talk about DLL manifests for compatibility.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The answer comes a bit late, but I had a similar problem, see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44658427/423913).

The problem is that the compatibility section of a manifest is ignored when applied to a DLL, it only works when applied to an EXE.

So if you don't control the EXE that will use your DLL and can't be sure that it has the correct manifest, the way to get around it is to get the ProductVersion from the kernel32.dll file. This neatly corresponds with the Windows version and seems pretty reliable (it is also recommended on [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/getting-the-system-version)).