# Get the Windows version correctly from a dll function call?

Tags: c++, c, windows, dll, manifest

Suppose I'm writing a multi-purpose dll which includes a function for getting the OS version:

```
void get_os_version(DWORD *major, DWORD *minor)
{
    OSVERSIONINFOEX osvi;

    ZeroMemory(&osvi, sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX));
    osvi.dwOsVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX);

    // deprecated but easier to use for this example's sake
    GetVersionEx((OSVERSIONINFO*)&osvi);

    *major = osvi.dwMajorVersion;
    *minor = osvi.dwMinorVersion;
}
```

For the Windows version to be retrieved correctly for versions higher than Windows 8, it is required to embed a manifest that specifies the supported platforms (see details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn481241(v=vs.85).aspx)).

So I disable automatic generation of a manifest for my dll file using the `/MANIFEST:NO` flag when compiling, and instead add the following manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges>
                <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel>
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>
    <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
        <application>
            <!-- Windows 10 --> 
            <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>
            <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
            <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>
            <!-- Windows Vista -->
            <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/> 
            <!-- Windows 7 -->
            <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
            <!-- Windows 8 -->
            <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
        </application>
    </compatibility>
</assembly>
```

, using the mt tool:

```
mt -manifest GetOsVersion.dll.manifest -outputresource:GetOsVersion.dll;#2
```

All good and no errors. Now to use the dll, I create a simple App.exe which loads the dll and calls its function:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DWORD major, minor;
    get_os_version(&major, &minor);
    printf("%d.%d\n", major, minor);
    return 0;
}
```

But when running App.exe on Windows 10, surprise surprise, the output is:

```
6.2
```

, which is the version for Windows 8. If I apply the manifest to the App.exe too:

```
mt -manifest GetOsVersion.dll.manifest -outputresource:App.exe;#1
```

, the output is the expected one:

```
10.0
```

Why is this happening? And can I solve this problem without adding a manifest to the executable?

I don't have control over the applications that will use my library, but I still want to correctly retrieve the OS version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative method for determining the actual operating system version is documented on the MSDN page ["Getting the System Version"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> To obtain the full version number for the operating system, call the GetFileVersionInfo function on one of the system DLLs, such as Kernel32.dll, then call VerQueryValue to obtain the `\\StringFileInfo\\<lang><codepage>\\ProductVersion` subblock of the file version information.

This will work from a DLL regardless of whether the application has a manifest.

(Of course, there is a reason that GetVersionInfo and friends don't return the actual operating system version: programmers have a nasty tendency to misuse this information.  You should seriously consider whether or not providing such a function in your DLL is really a good idea.)

Comment: +1 Thanks, I will try this out. Side note: I don't export such a function in my actual dll, it is called inside the dll for statistics and debugging purposes; I made the example this way so that I could easily demonstrate the problem

Comment: OK, that's a legitimate use.  I won't edit my answer though because the warning might still be relevant to future readers. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Complementing the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44665238/423913), here is some starter code for anyone else who wants to implement it:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "version")

static void print_version()
{
    DWORD buffer_size = GetFileVersionInfoSize(_T("kernel32.dll"), NULL);
    if (buffer_size == 0)
    {
        // get error from GetLastError()
        return;
    }

    VOID *buffer = malloc(buffer_size);
    if (buffer == NULL)
    {
        // out of memory
        return;
    }

    if (!GetFileVersionInfo(_T("kernel32.dll"), 0, buffer_size, buffer))
    {
        goto error;
    }

    VS_FIXEDFILEINFO *version = NULL;
    UINT version_len = 0;
    if (!VerQueryValue(buffer,
                       _T("\\"),
                       (LPVOID*)&version,
                       &version_len))
    {
        goto error;
    }

    _tprintf(_T("Version is: %u.%u\n"),
             HIWORD(version->dwProductVersionMS),
             LOWORD(version->dwProductVersionMS));

error:
    free(buffer);
}
```

And the output on Windows 10 is:

```
Version is 10.0
```

Answer (score 1):

[App (executable) manifest MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/application-executable-manifest) describes this matter rather explicitly:

> The compatibility section of the app (executable) manifest introduced in Windows helps the operating system determine the versions of Windows an app was designed to target.

Compatibility (and other application settings, such as DPI awareness) are completely ignored if manifest is not an executable manifest. This makes sense because otherwise there would be possible manifest conflicts occurring between manifests in different dlls.

Comment: Thanks, indeed it makes sense to not allow such manifest tags into a dll. But then it seems that there is no reliable way to get the OS version from a dll...

Answer (score 0):

Most of the nodes in a manifest applies to the whole process and is only read from the main .exe module:

> The [compatibility section of the app (executable) manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/application-executable-manifest) introduced in Windows helps the operating system determine the versions of Windows an app was designed to target.

You should use `GetProcAddress` and `CoCreateInstance` to check if the feature you need is present, not the Windows version.

With a little work, `GetProcAddress` can also be used to figure out what version you are on if you really need that information. Look at the minimum OS version of various kernel32 and user32 functions on MSDN...

Comment: The thing is I don't want to target my application for a specific version of Windows, I just want to get the Windows version. (so yeah, my hypothesis that I was getting the Windows version was actually wrong)

Comment: Getting the Windows version is OK if you are writing it to a log file but you should not be using it to decide which APIs you can call.